# Python program that reads a txt file of integers, and returns all nonzeros

Tags: python

I want my program to return all the numbers in the txt file except `0`.
The variables in my txt file are as follows `[10 20 30 40 0 5 3 21 0]`

```
import os
num= ''
f1 = open("3data.txt", 'r')
for line in f1:
  num = line.split("0")
  print(num)
```

The result is `['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' ', ' 5 3 21 ', '']`
I want `0` to be removed, but not the `0` from numbers like `10`?

Comment: The argument to split is the character it is to use for where to split the string. You would need to split on spaces first, then test for values that are 0 and not include them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fin = []
f = open("3data.txt", "r")    
theFullText = f.read()
words = theFullText.split()

for word in words:

   fin.append(word)

remove = '0'
fin = [i for i in fin if i != remove]


print(fin)
```

Input:

```
10 3 43 20 5 7 0 3 5 7
123
23
3434 434 3 4 34
```

Output:

```
['10', '3', '43', '20', '5', '7', '3', '5', '7', '123', '23', '3434', 
'434', '3', '4', '34']
```

Comment: It failed to remove any zeros from the list.

Comment: Updated, try now. Please for future post adequate amount of your texted file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove will only eliminate the first instance of the element, if you wanna keep the line as a string try this:

```
import os
num= ''
f1 = open("3data.txt", 'r')
for line in f1:
  x = line.split()
  print(x)
  x = list(filter(lambda a: a != '0', x))
  print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
with open('3data.txt','r') as fp:
  for line in fp:
    line = line.translate(None,'][') #no translation matrix, just deletion
    elems = line.split() #separator is space
    elems = [x if x !='0' else '' for x in elems] #replace the '0' by empty string ''
    print(elems) #print the newly generated lines
```

input:

```
[10 20 30 40 0 5 3 21 0]
```

output:

```
['10', '20', '30', '40', '', '5', '3', '21', '']
```

explanations:

- You open the file
- You read each line of the file, remove the brackets via the translate methode
- Split each line into the different numbers
- repack the elems and replace all '0' by ''
- print the new line

Answer (score -1):

Using your code->

```
import os
num= ''
f1 = open("3data.txt", 'r')
for line in f1:
    if line !="0":
       print(num)
```

Comment: The problem with the code you gave me, is that print returns nothing. The point of my program is to return all non zeroes. How would I go about making this applicable?

Comment: try to replace "num" with "line", my fault, num is not necessary